# Upvote not appearing in top bar, possibly linked to Necromancer badge

Tags: bug, reputation, badges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Today, I received a fifth upvote on one of my answers [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/58633/16683). As this was the fifth upvote on a new answer to an old question, it also earned me a [Necromancer badge](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer).

The upvote and its +10 rep are displayed both on [my profile](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16683/orthocresol?tab=reputation) as well as on the [post timeline](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/58633/timeline) (moderator version of timeline shown below):

[image: Profile reputation]

[image: Timeline]

However, it's not appearing in the top bar (which reflects a badge earned with an upvote):

[image: Top bar]

I assumed this wasn't intended behaviour, so here's my [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346191

Comment: Indeed, it seems like the same issue, but it was supposedly solved. I'll drop a comment on Oded's answer.